# IF statement error new variable input python

Tags: python, if-statement

The problem here is that I just cant get python to check if Currency1 is in string, and if its not then print that there is an error,but if Currency1 IS in string then move on and ask the user to input Currency2, and then check it again.

Comment: Doing type checking in python means *you're doing it wrong*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `try-except`:

```
def get_currency(msg):
    curr = input(msg)
    try:
        float(curr)
        print('You must enter text. Numerical values are not accepted at this stage')
        return get_currency(msg)  #ask for input again
    except:
        return curr               #valid input, return the currency name

curr1=get_currency('Please enter the currency you would like to convert:')
curr2=get_currency('Please enter the currency you would like to convert into:')
ExRate = float(input('Please enter the exchange rate in the order of, 1 '+curr1+' = '+curr2)) 
Amount = float(input('Please enter the amount you would like to convert:'))
print (Amount*ExRate)
```

**output:**

```
$ python3 foo.py

Please enter the currency you would like to convert:123
You must enter text. Numerical values are not accepted at this stage
Please enter the currency you would like to convert:rupee
Please enter the currency you would like to convert into:100
You must enter text. Numerical values are not accepted at this stage
Please enter the currency you would like to convert into:dollar
Please enter the exchange rate in the order of, 1 rupee = dollar 50
Please enter the amount you would like to convert: 10
500.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You were actually trying for:

```
if type(Currency1) in (float, int):
   ...
```

but `isinstance` is better here:

```
if isinstance(Currency1,(float,int)):
   ...
```

or even better, you can use the `numbers.Number` abstract-base class:

```
import numbers
if isinstance(Currency1,numbers.Number):
```

---

Although ... `Currency1 = str(raw_input(...))` will guarantee that `Currency1` is a string (not an integer or float).  Actually, `raw_input` makes that guarantee and the extra `str` here is just redundant :-).

If you want a function to check if a string can be converted to a number, then I think the easiest way would be to just try it and see:

```
def is_float_or_int(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: Hey thanks.. But the actual problem here is that after I check if Currency1 is an string, I cant manage to let the user enter the next value for Currency2. It's giving me a syntax error.    
   
     elif:
     Currency2 = str(input('Please enter the currency you would like to convert into:'))) #This bit doesn't work